# How to store user-controls for future editing

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Can somebody help me to figure out with - how to store correctly Array of Controls added programmatically in my application?

To be more explicitly, I have a function that create programmatically some Labels and PictureBoxes, and added it to Panel Control.

```
var lbLip = new Label { Text = @"LIP :", Location = new Point(5, 20), Size = new Size(29, 13) };
var lbLipVar = new Label { Text = "", Location = new Point(32, 20), Size = new Size(79, 13) };

var lbRip = new Label { Text = @"RIP :", Location = new Point(5, 40), Size = new Size(31, 13) };
var lbRipVar = new Label { Text = "", Location = new Point(32, 40), Size = new Size(70, 13) };
var imgBox = new PictureBox { Image = Image.FromFile(@"data\icon\red.png"), Location = new Point(100, 40), Size = new Size(16, 11) };

var lbPid = new Label { Text = @"PID :", Location = new Point(5, 60), Size = new Size(31, 13) };
var lbPidVar = new Label { Text = "", Location = new Point(32, 60), Size = new Size(37, 13) };

var lbTime = new Label { Text = @"Time :", Location = new Point(80, 60), Size = new Size(39, 13) };
var lbTimeVar = new Label { Text = "", Location = new Point(115, 60), Size = new Size(49, 13) };

            var arrayLb = new Control[9];
            arrayLb[0] = lbLip;
            arrayLb[1] = lbLipVar;
            arrayLb[2] = lbRip;
            arrayLb[3] = lbRipVar;
            arrayLb[4] = imgBox;
            arrayLb[5] = lbPid;
            arrayLb[6] = lbPidVar;
            arrayLb[7] = lbTime;
            arrayLb[8] = lbTimeVar;

            plObject.Controls.AddRange(arrayLb);
```

And now the problem is - how to store this array of Controls for the future updating (editing/removing).
Can somebody suggests a solution how to do this right?

My idea was to create a list of controls

```
public static List<Control> LiControls = new List<Control>();
```

and store in it. However I have a lots of Controls to add (~200) - and its hard to handle them all.

Comment: My first thought is to write an XML file. You could store the types of controls in the file and then use reflection to instantiate them and set properties on load.

Comment: DO NOT store them in a static field! When are you going to use them ?

Comment: Eventually you will add them to plObject.Controls.Why do you need to store them also somewhere else?

Comment: the problem is in storring that controls - to future content updating - and the question is how to do that right.

Answer (score 0):

I would have create a seperate `Serializable` class with the properties you need to persist. You can save it to an xml file with the `XmlSerializer` and if you need to save more properties in the future, just add them to the class and the `XmlSerializer` will save and load the new properties properly. Good luck !